# One dimensional to two dimensional array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, format

First I have an array like:

```
arr = [[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a]]
```

I can 'flatten' it using

```
arr = Array.prototype.concat.apply([],arr)
```

or using a for-next loop and push.apply

Then I got:

```
[r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a,r,g,b,a]
```

How do I get it back to its original format as easy as possible?

Comment: Just for fun in JavaScript 1.6 (maybe jQuery) `arr.join().match(/\d+,\d+,\d+,\d+/g).map(function(s) { return s.split(",") } )`

Comment: Isn't it a possibility to work with one format? Saves a lot of looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
var old = [];
for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; index+= 4)
    old.push( arr.slice(index, index + 4) );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var newArr = [];
while(arr.length){
    newArr.push(arr.splice(0,4));
}
```

Comment: This is very slow with big arrays, since every time the array has to be reindexed